# XFCE Missing running app buttons

Tags: xfce

I've installed xfce4 on Ubuntu, the running app is disappeared on the panel? Look like this:

[image]

Google Chrome, Terminal don't show on the bottom panel.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by add panel item "Window Buttons"